# Chess position evaluation using neural network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm working on an AI that should be able to play chess. I want to make use of `keras` neural networks to evaluate position on the board. I would like to teach the NN by playing plenty of games between AI and AI. I already have *alpha-beta pruning* implemented.

My idea was to create a csv file with positions of every single game the AI has played. I would chose variables I would like to store there. Very simple example:

```
"white_pawns","black_pawns","white_queens","black_queens","white_pawns_on_side","white_won"
3,7,1,2,0,False
3,5,3,0,1,True
```

I would like to train a model using these values and then use it to evaluate current board position. So the main question is:

**How to make a neural network output a value of position given these variables?** Eg. `0` when it's draw or `1` when we are one pawn up. `keras` preferred, but I'm open to any other `python` library.

I would also be grateful if you could dispel my few other doubts.
Are there any flaws in that approach? Wouldn't every position from a single game make the neural network overfitted? Maybe I should pick only few positions from each game?

Comment: What are all of the data points that you are using? Each individual piece has different value based on its position on the board (eg. pawn) and based on other pieces positions (eg. number of pieces on white tiles for a white bishop)

Comment: @Krish all of these will be stored in the csv. I wanted to keep the example simple, but it will store much more data, including pawn structure etc.

Comment: From a purely statistical approach you need to get as much variance in your data points as possible. I'm not sure whether it'll be computationally feasible to get enough data points with only one data point per game, so I'd recommend creating an algorithm that picks a maximum of 2 data points per game that are reasonably spread out. A better move would be to use a chess game data set: https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/chess and scraping data from over 20,000 matches.

Comment: @Krish Good idea. Do you maybe know, how to implement a neural network so that it produces an evaluating number from this input? Eg. 0 when it's draw or 1 when we are 1 pawn up?

Comment: Look up reinforcement learning (which is a massive subject which books have been written about) to see how learning can be done from self-play data, without having the expected outputs in advance as you would in supervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know this, but when a human evaluates the board, he is not only looking at the material—but also looking in the positions of the pieces. Secondly, with this csv, you can't decide what is a better movie if the thing you see is only true or false. This is why the engine's evaluation is numerical. Or you want it to output a number from -1 to 1, and then it is the score? Looking to do the same thing but do 1 for a white win, -1 for a black win or 0 for a draw (in the dataset file). If you want to do this with me, hit me up (is there a messaging service for stack overflow?).

## conclusion

the input should be a numerical representation for the board, in my opinion, and the target should not be a classifier but a numerical classifier. it is actually simpler.

I have a python engine that I am working on and this is an opportunity to meet new people that are interested in the things I am.

only saying, this is my first answer so if something is unclear please make a comment and I will try to help!

also, like krish said this can be implemented with reinforcement learning. but first you need to make a dqn (deep q networks (q learning is a really popular reinforcement learning algorithm)) and for that you need another network. because if not, this will take a lot of time to train.